# problem taking the value of getElementByID

Tags: javascript, forms

```
var baseUrl = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
var pokemonid = document.getElementById('pokemon_id').value;

function fetchPokemon(){
    fetch(`${baseUrl}&{pokemonid}`)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    }) 
}

fetchPokemon();
```

This code return me [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20&limit=20'](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20&limit=20%27) at url, how can I change pokeomonid.value for return the number or name on the input?

Comment: Here, you seem to be grabbing the `value` of the input as soon as your page loads. You might want to wait for the user to press a button, or at least type something. You're going to need [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), and you will call your fetch function from there. Also in the URL, `{pokemonid}` won't get interpolated (replaced) with the value. It should be `${pokemonid}` with a dollar sign

Comment: Why is it tagged PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem using async await:

```
  const insertPokemon = async(a) => {
    const respuesta = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+a)
    const data = await respuesta.json()
    const {value} = data
    console.log(data)
    nombre.textContent = data.name
    id.textContent = "ID_"+data.id
    img.src = data.sprites.front_default
    pokeTypes.textContent = data.types[0].type.name;
    pokeTypes2.textContent = data.types[1].type.name;  
    stats(value)  
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault(); 
    pokeTypes.textContent = "";
    pokeTypes2.textContent = "";
    insertPokemon(pokeselect.value.toLowerCase());
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).